# Hierarchical option tree in python

Tags: python

I am creating a module that simulates keyboard strokes. I want to be able to select if I want to press or release some special buttons. Some of those appear more than once (like Left or Right Alt) so I need to replicate this as well, add this together and you get a hierarchy like:

*button > left or right > up or down*

The tricky part here is that I want to be able to call each layer individually (no dicts).

The final result I am aiming for should be a selection of options like the following example:

```
>>>print alt()
'Alt'
>>>print alt.left()
'Alt Left'
>>>print alt.left.up()
'Alt Left Up'
```

I think there is an easy solution but I can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just a tuple, like `alt, left, up`?

Comment: Can you please show me how you create multiple layers with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but for having the behaviour you describe in your question, you could try something like this:

```
class Cmd:

    def __init__(self, key, parent=None):
        self.key = key
        self.parent = parent

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return "%s %s" % (self.parent(), self.key) if self.parent else self.key
```

Demo:

```
alt = Cmd("Alt")
alt.left = Cmd("Left", alt)
alt.left.up = Cmd("Up", alt.left)

print alt()
print alt.left()
print alt.left.up()
```

Comment: I think this just did the trick. I use the strings to call the specific buttons with the according options. Since there multiple buttons with same set of additional options... You see where I'm going.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to store each 'node' as an object with attributes in reference to other node objects.

Comment: Isn't there a way using just classes and magic functions? It would sure work but it seems a little brutal to me to create objects with additional references.